# I have a database on Parse.com where the values are strings. Is there a way I can split this one attribute into multiple?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I'm creating an app on android that helps users find an apartment around campus by letting you choose the complex, the building inside of that complex, and finally the apartment number.  These are done in listviews first starting with a list of the complexes.  After this, it opens up a list of the buildings etc.

All of the information is stored in Parse.  I have a table called 'Parent' That has all of the complex information stored, and then a 'Children' table that stores the complex, building, a building color (if it has one) and an apartment number.

The app is already created on IOS by a friend of mine and now he wants me to make the android app. When the database was created, it was created in a very messy way.  In the 'Children' table, there is a childKey that stores the complex, building, color and apartment number as a string separated only by spaces.

I'm looking for the simplest way to create multiple attributes from this one childKey.  Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

Parent Table:

```
 apartmentName = Campus West
 apartmentKey  = CW
```

Children Table:

```
 childKey   = CW T 10337 ('Parent apartmentKey', 'building', 'apartment#')
 latitude   = 12.345
 longitude  = 67.890
```

I want the Children Table to have:

```
 apartmentKey = CW
 building     = T
 apartment#   = 10337
 latitude     = 12.345
 longitude    = 67.890
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply parse through the string data and create a JSONObject that would allow you to grab any specific data you might need for each "Children"?

#### Parse childKey String

```
String data = "CW T 10337 ('Parent apartmentKey', 'building', 'apartment#')";
String[] dataList = data.split(" "); // Make String array based on space
```

#### Create JSONObject

```
JSONObject childrenData = new JSONObject();
childrenData.put("apartment_key", dataList[0]);
childrenData.put("building", dataList[1]);
childrenData.put("apartment_no", dataList[2]);
// Not sure what the data in the () is as you do not state its use/where to save it

// Now add the longitude and latitude
childrenData.put("latitude", mLatitude);
childrenData.put("longitude", mLongitude);
```

You could then pass the JSONObject along and read from it

#### Read JSONObject

```
String apartmentKey = childrenData.getString("apartment_key");
String building = childrenData.getString("building");
int apartmentNumber = childrenData.getInt("apartment_no");
```

Or you could save the JSON object to the device and grab it later on if need be.

This might not be EXACTLY how you tend to implement it but I could see JSONObject being useful as it allows you to store multiple attributes via a key and a value. As long that you are consistent in the database childKey field then this should be fine. If not you could set up some additional logic to catch any special cases.

**EDIT:**
In case you haven't heard of/used JSONObjects before here is a quick layout of a JSON object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "array": [{"value1", 1}, {"value2", 2}]
        "string": "value"
        "int": 1
    }    
}
```

The first part of a JSON object is the key. In "int": 1, the "int" is the key and its value is 1.

Here's a good link about [JSON](http://json-schema.org/example1.html)

Comment: This is good.  The only problem is the app actively grabs from parse.  We are dealing with 1.75k entries in children.  Would putting a JSON file of that size into the app be reasonable?  

Edit: Do you know if I can take a JSON file and put it into a Parse database?

Comment: I have never used Parse before, but it seems very neat and will look into it. From some quick searching it seems that (correct me if I'm wrong) you can store objects (JSONObjects) in a Parse field (see this link: https://www.parse.com/questions/store-json-in-a-field). I can't for sure say that a JSON file of that size would be reasonable but with only 1.75k entries in your database, I can't image it being too large.